# Problem with MS Excel 2007

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-excel-2007

I get an error dialog that states "this workbook contains no unbount sheets".  It then freezes my session of excel.  I cannot find a help topic that relates to this problem.  Has anyone seen this before?

**Update**
This error occurred when I attempted to open a workbook that is dependent upon several others. I have set the workbook up to return values from other workbooks to get a current view of the status of several items as they transition from production to ready-to-ship. There is no VBA coding involved, all the returned values are the results of `MATCH` or `VLOOKUP` functions. My workstation computer has only Office 2007 resident, and it none of my colleagues seem to ever have had this error in their collective experience.

To clarify - the dialog box has the message: "workbook has no bound sheets.". The only option is to click "OK" (or to close the box with the red X). Either action freezes that session of Excel.

Thanks for your attention to my plight.

Comment: @warren Your dad will have to register both his SU and SO accounts to regain ownership of this question

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try to save the workbook in an older Excel version (say XP, 2003) and try to reopen it.